# meteor display image with variable source

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using meteor.js and playing around with a simple application. I have a form on my page and once submitted the data is inserted into a database. I have a 'feed' of data on the left side of my page which updates when a new entry in the database is submitted, displaying the data. This is basic data at present about countries and populations etc. My question is how to mix a js variable to vary the source of an image file thats loaded in this 'feed' - hopefully explained below.

So, in code, I have this:

```
<template name="mainLeftCol">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        {{> form}}
    </div>
</template>

<template name="mainBody">
    {{> mainLeftCol}}

    <div class="col-sm-7">
        {{#each dbEntry}}
            {{> formItem}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

and in a js file I have the event code for when the form is submitted:

```
Template.mainLeftCol.events({
  'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    var country = $(e.target).find('[id=country]').val()
    prefix = country.slice(0,3);

    if (prefix === 'Eng') {
      console.log("Eng is for England");
    } 

    var spot = {
      country: country,
      continent: $(e.target).find('[id=continent]').val(),
    };

    spot._id = Spots.insert(spot);
  }
});
```

The formItems are being displayed using the following template which outputs the 'variables' that were input in the form:

```
<template name="formItem">
{{#Animate}}
    <div class="panel panel-default spot animate">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h5 class="pull-right">{{country}}</h5>
        <h4><mark><b>{{continent}}</b></mark></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <img src="Eng.png" class="img-circle pull-right"> 
      </div>
    </div>
{{/Animate}}
</template>
```

As you can see in this template I have hardcoded "Eng.png" as the source for the image. What I would like to do is based on the prefix variable which slices the country field is to have the template display a different image (they're flags) based on the country on the template.

How can I mix a JS variable from my events code into the source of the image file in my template code?

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i got i right, but if you want to change the image (flag) according to the country try something like this:

Build a Template helper "prefix" which outputs the current country prefix.

Prefix helper:

```js
Template.formItem.helpers({
     countryPrefix: function () {

        var country = $(e.target).find('[id=country]').val()
        return country.slice(0,3);

    }
});
```

In your Template you can now:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <img src="{{countryPrefix}}.png" class="img-circle pull-right"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Markus this is a great idea, I'm just struggling to create the helper. How can I reference the 'country' variable in the mainLeftCol.events code in the helper code?

Comment: as a workaround if I add the prefix to my "spot" array to be inserted into the db I can use the {{prefix}} helper which works :-)

Comment: I just updated my initial answer and added the Template.helper. If this is working fpr you can mark this answer as correct. :)

Comment: Markus, will e.target be in scope in the helper function?